# Opening a book reader app at the some page where the app was closed

Tags: iphone

I have an app which is like reading a book, and while reading if user hit home button on iPhone, and again reopen the app , it should open on the same page in which user was previously, i have got x position for all the page, since book is in vertical scrolling. plz let me know where to implement the information.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)_scrollView {
    CGPoint p = _scrollView.contentOffset;
    NSLog(@"x = %f",p.x);
    AppDelegate_iPhone *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    delegate.dataValue = p.x;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to save state information.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)_scrollView {
    CGPoint p = _scrollView.contentOffset;
    NSLog(@"x = %f",p.x);
    AppDelegate_iPhone *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    delegate.dataValue = p.x;

    // save state
    NSUserDefaults* ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [ud setInteger: p.x forKey @"x-position"];
    [ud synchronize];
}
```

to retrieve saved state

```
NSUserDefaults* ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
int x = [ud integerForKey: @"x-position"];
```

Comment: I HAVE TAKEN NSUserDefaults, but i didn't know the thing that where to implement the information, suppose if user was reading page 3 and click on home button, again after opening the app it should open page 3, so where in the code have to mention about that.

Comment: You can save the current page position in the applicationWillTerminate: method of your app delegate.

Comment: Thanks for the information, however i have written the value in application will terminate method, i have saved the value in appdelegate and have called in application will terminate, it didn't work.

Comment: -(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)_scrollView {
  
 CGPoint p = _scrollView.contentOffset;
 NSLog(@"x = %f",p.x);
 
 AppDelegate_iPhone *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 delegate.dataValue = p.x;
}
 i have got the value in delegate.dataValue, if i want to store and retrieve from NSUserDefaults, how did i do that.

Comment: Ferruccio , i have saved the information in Application did Enter Background, however when i press the home button it save the current position, and when i restart the app, its not coming where i left, it is coming from the first page.